# Accessing last screenshot and deleting it from gallery using cordova in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, screenshot

I have an ionic-Cordova app, now I have a requirement to prevent a user(of an ios device)from taking a screenshot into my app. I wanted to take gallery access of the ios device and immediately after capturing the screenshot, wanted to delete that screenshot from the user's photo library.

To implement that:-

1.What Cordova permission do I need to get access to the user's photo library in ios?

2.Which Cordova plugin do I need to delete the last taken screenshot from the user's photo library in ios.

I don't know how I can fulfill this requirement. Please help, your help is much appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Even when you try to delete a photo, there's going to be a pop-up confirmation from the user. They can decline. And even if the agree to delete, the photo just goes to the Recently Deleted folder.

Comment: Hi @aheze, Thanks For the reply, Is there any other way possible to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Most likely not. Lots of people have tried ways to prevent screenshots, but it's pretty much impossible, at least currently.

Comment: try Plugins to prevent screenshots: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot

Comment: Hi @NajamUsSaqib this plugin will not work in ios. I have to implement for ios. could you please suggest something for ios? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This is an essentially pointless goal while other cameras exist in the world; There are some commercial packages which claim to obscure screenshots. You need to balance your requirement vs the cost of those packages.